# WPF Binding two dependency properties of the same control but two datacontexts needed

Tags: c#, wpf

I have two controls in a grid.

```
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" TextAlignment="Center" />
   <TextBox Visibility="{Binding ElementName=EditMode,Source={Binding RelativeSource=
                   {RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}, 
                   Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}"  Text="{Binding Name}" 
                   TextAlignment="Center" />
```

I am trying to implement something like an editable/non editable behaviour. I know i might choose for a TextBox and simply change  the IsEditable property but still, in my scenarion i would need to DataContext, at least that's what i am thinking of.

In my example, the TextBlock works fine, and the Text property on the TextBox also works fine but for the Visibility part, i want to bind to a data property ( EditMode which is a boolean) found on some other layer. Is there a way to change the DataContext to that, but only for the Visibility ? The Text property should remain as it is now.

Should i try a hack, to define an invisible checkbox, change IsChecked when my Edit button is clicked and bind directly to that ? I will try this. I think this way, no DataContext changing is needed.

Comment: Why don't put `EditMode` property into current data context?

Comment: What about
`<TextBox Visibility="{Binding ElementName=EditMode, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}" />`

Comment: @ Denis, if i put it there, i will get to some collections iteration in order to change it when my Edit button is clicked. That's why i'm trying to keep it at a higher level, meaning in the datacontext of my Window.

Comment: @ rraszewski by doing, that i am using a wrong datacontext, the one used for the Text property.

Comment: Following MVVM will make structure more clear: view-model (data-content thing) should provide all necessary properties for generic view to be able to represent data. If you lack one, then simply add it. You can have property `Name` to bind to `TextBlock.Text` and property `IsNameEditable` (or whatever) for `Visibility`. Last one can even be of `Visibility` type to void necessity of having converter. This way you will have all properties in same *data-content* - no problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@FrumRoll is correct that you can access a property that is not in the set `DataContext` object using a `RelativeSource Binding`. However, I'm not sure that their code is quite right... try this:

```
<TextBox Visibility="{Binding DataContext.EditMode, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
    AncestorType={x:Type YourXamlPrefix:MainWindow}}}, Converter={StaticResource 
    BoolToVis}}" Text="{Binding Name}" TextAlignment="Center" />
```

Clearly, you'll need to change the `YourXamlPrefix` value with your local XAML Namespace Prefix and `MainWindow` with the name/type of your `Window` if it is not called `MainWindow`. This also assumes that your `EditMode` property has been defined in that `Window`.

This *may* also work, but is not specifically looking for your exact `Window`, so *may* have some problems:

```
<TextBox Visibility="{Binding DataContext.EditMode, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
    AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}" 
    Text="{Binding Name}" TextAlignment="Center" />
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you were almost there, you should be able to use a RelativeSource to do this. The issue is that you misused ElementName, ElementName is to bind to a property of a named source and would be used instead of RelativeSource. What you meant to use was Path, which is optional as seen below.

```
<TextBox Visibility="{Binding DataContext.EditMode, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, 
               Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}"
         Text="{Binding Name}" TextAlignment="Center" />
```

Comment: indeed this seems fine but i get this error : A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'Source' property of type 'Binding'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.

Comment: You should remove "Source={Binding " and the ending "}". Set either a Source or a RelativeSource, not both of them like you did.

Comment: @RobvanDaal This is correct, I missed this error when I copied the OP. I have fixed the syntax.